# Elastic Search - How to combine multiple must clauses?

Tags: elasticsearch

> I have the following index schema for a nested object:

```
      "workExperiences": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "isCurrentWorkplace": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "title": {
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

The data for this is as follows:

```
{
    "hits": [{
            "_source": {
                "workExperiences": [{
                        "isCurrentWorkPlace": true,
                        "title": {
                            "name": "Some name",
                            "id": 259
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "isCurrentWorkPlace": false,
                        "title": {
                            "name": "Some other name",
                            "id": 256
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "isCurrentWorkPlace": false,
                        "title": {
                            "name": "another name",
                            "id": 257
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "_source": {
                "workExperiences": [{
                        "isCurrentWorkPlace": true,
                        "title": {
                            "name": "another workplace",
                            "id": 260
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "isCurrentWorkPlace": false,
                        "title": {
                            "name": "Some other name",
                            "id": 256
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "isCurrentWorkPlace": false,
                        "title": {
                            "name": "another name",
                            "id": 257
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now if i do simple queries like find a workplace whose "isCurrentWorkplace" is true and whose title.id is 259, then it works perfectly:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 30,
    "_source": [
        "workExperiences.*"
    ],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "workExperiences",
                            "query": {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [{
                                            "term": {
                                                "workExperiences.title.id": 259
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "term": {
                                                "workExperiences.isCurrentWorkPlace": true
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Now the problem is that I need to combine these must clauses. For
>   example, I need to find a record whose "isCurrentWorkplace" is true
>   and "title.id" is 259 **AND** whose "isCurrentWorkplace" is false and
>   "title.id" is 256.

For this, i created the following query:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 30,
    "_source": [
        "workExperiences.*"
    ],
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "nested": {
                            "path": "workExperiences",
                            "query": {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [{
                                            "bool": {
                                                "must": [{
                                                        "terms": {
                                                            "workExperiences.title.id": [259]
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "term": {
                                                            "workExperiences.isCurrentWorkPlace": true
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "bool": {
                                                "must": [{
                                                        "term": {
                                                            "workExperiences.title.id": 256
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "term": {
                                                            "workExperiences.isCurrentWorkPlace": false
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This however, does not work. Can anyone help me in figuring out what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you are trying to achieve is: records where (`"workExperiences.isCurrentWorkplace": true` and `"workExperiences.title.id": 259`) **OR** (`"workExperiences.isCurrentWorkplace": false` and `"workExperiences.title.id": 256`). So you require `should` clause instead of `must` clause:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "workExperiences",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "workExperiences.isCurrentWorkplace": true
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "workExperiences.title.id": 259
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "workExperiences.isCurrentWorkplace": false
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "workExperiences.title.id": 256
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In case you mean that a doc should appear if the same doc contains more than two objects where one object under `workExperiences` has (`"workExperiences.isCurrentWorkplace": true and "workExperiences.title.id": 259`) **AND** one has (`"workExperiences.isCurrentWorkplace": false and "workExperiences.title.id": 256`), then the query will be:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "workExperiences",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "workExperiences.isCurrentWorkplace": true
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "workExperiences.title.id": 259
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "workExperiences",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "workExperiences.isCurrentWorkplace": false
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "workExperiences.title.id": 256
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes the 2nd case with AND was the requirement and this works! thanks!